# Get Internal Server Error when Parameter contains ssh or scp in PHP on Linux server

Tags: php, linux, .htaccess, ssh

I just create a file 'test.php' for a demo purpose and uploaded on server, code as follows,

```
echo $_REQUEST["email"];
die;
```

When I call this page url `http://domain.com/mytest/test.php?email=ssh.vp@gmail.com`
 Then i am getting Internal Server Error.
And when **I remove the `ssh` or `scp` from email parameter then works fine.**
When I add `ssh` or `scp` in the email parameter then that time i get Internal Server Error.

Comment: My guess: it's something in your .htaccess file. Either in mytest or in domain.com. Could also be in the httpd.conf file too..